# Consumed DTUs unavailable in the azure database monitoring

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-monitoring

I would like to see DTU consumption on an azure database in the monitoring chart. When entering the dialog to configure the chart I am able to select percentage metrics, I am unable to select physical metrics like DTU used or DTU limit.

The database is in S3 tier, is the DB Monitoring somehow tight to the database tier? What needs to be done so I can monitor physical DTUs consumed.

[image: Monitoring Config]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry for the confusion caused here.

What is actually happening is that two metrics of different units cannot be displayed in the monitoring chart at the same time. Due to this limitation, you cannot select multiple metrics with different units of measure in this list. You have already selected "DTU percentage" so it will not let you select "DTU used".

If you un-select "DTU percentage" you will be able to select "DTU used".

We will work to make this clearer in the experience.